# what should be test input data for a function to ensure that function works fine for complete allowed range

Tags: validation, testing, input

I have a function f(n) which returns sum from 1 to n ie

```
f(1)=1
f(2)=3 
f(3)=6
```

Suppose this function have some issue and n can range from 1 to 100000.
How can i test it by providing minimum number of test cases. like n=1 can be 1 test case. n=50 can be another test case.
I mean is there any algorithm which can generate what all inputs can i test to ensure that all input from 1 to 100000 are working fine.

Comment: What is your intent here? Write unit tests for the function?

Comment: i mean, suppose i test this function for 6 values - 1,10,100,1000,10000,100000, if these 6 cases Pass. Can i say that that function is ok for for 1-100000. Basically i am looking for a set of inputs. If set is Pass, then i may conclude that whole range 1-100000 is Pass.

Comment: @sruti, i dont know the intent. May be you can take intent of your choice and explain me.

Comment: One way to think of tests is corner cases, invalid cases and normal cases. For f(1), it's a single element, a corner case that could have been missed, you could test for that. If there is something about the range of numbers (like overflow for too large inputs), test that. Test for some normal case : f(10) or whatever. Also see what happens with invalid stuff, like f(-1) or f(100001), etc.  Thinking of ways to break it might help.

Answer (score 0):

A common cliche in software testing is that you can never test every possible case. In a bounded and simple case such as your example, testing the entire range of input is possible, but it's not worth it. So, we take a more pragmatic approach -- this means working fine in happy paths and gracefully failing (in the case of computer programs) in invalid scenarios.

Let us look at your example :

> f(n) = 1+2+...+n

What's the least possible input: 1 -- this input has only one item in the series. So, test for that value of n.

> f(1) = 1?

Next, for n=2...100000, does it make a difference if you pick 2 or 100 or 10000 or 987? No. So, test for any one or two of them, picked at random.

> Say, f(10)=55?

Next, the negative cases: does your function operate only within the range? Here comes the tricky part, there are endless possibilities. 
For the lower bounds, one can test for n=0 and some negative number?

> f(0) and f(-1) throws exception?

For the higher bounds, 
The hope is people would stop at 100000 and not over it. 
Test for 100000 - make sure, it still works. And test another large number to make it fail.

> f(100000) = 4999950000?
>   f(100001) throws exception?

However, even this is too much. f(10) is redundant, because f(100000) and f(1) already test if the addition is right. (We expect the programmer did not write code saying fail for everything except 1 and 100000!).

That leaves the n values: -1, 0, 1, 100000, 100001